# Can i fool the android browser to cache mp4 file by changing its extension on server side as jpg?

Tags: android, html, caching, video

my android browser doesn't seem to cache a html5 video with  tag, since every time the page reloads, the flux increases.

so i changed the .mp4 file to .jpg on the server side, hoping my browser caches the fake .jpg.

problem is, how can I use the cached jpg and change it back to .mp4 and add it to the  src?

searched loads of web pages, couldn't find an answer to access the cached file. some said it's security issues that javascript can't access file system.

so any ideas that i can access the cached file or cache the mp4 on my android phone?

Thank you!!

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this issue? @LukeChen

Comment: @Chris No sir... I failed to cache the mp4 files. and I have to use the stream to download the video every time.